# what does global mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, global

I've been looking at a viewport plugin and don't understand what `global` means.
Here is the url [in-viewport.js](https://github.com/vvo/in-viewport/blob/master/in-viewport.js)
It is not defined anywhere and in the webdeveloper tools from Chrome it returns undefined when I type `global` as a watch.

Comment: `global` is the `window` object in a browser environment

Comment: @Icepickle — Why are you using a comment to submit an answer? (Which is wrong BTW, the question is asking about a variable called `global` and the OP has already tested that it isn't defined in their browser).

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Comment: nodejs global keyword.

Comment: @Icepickle It clearly isn't!

Comment: @JonSG Yeah, your version is a more safe way of saying it. When I see somebody is using the webdeveloper tools, I am assuming it is web, that's why I also mentioned the browser environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global` is the equivalent of `window` in Node.

You're using the wrong file, that one is not ready to be used in the browser. Use this one:

https://github.com/vvo/in-viewport/blob/master/build/in-viewport.min.js

Comment: So they compile it into an environment where `window` is injected for the `global` variable? It would be nice to see that build step and have a link to its docs.

Comment: [browserify](http://browserify.org/) essentially renames `global` into `window`, as far as I know. Here's the build step https://github.com/vvo/in-viewport/blob/9ca9f9172187b749dc5a4ae8f6f48f1f60fec147/package.json#L7